# Windows 10 shows command prompt when clicking Display Settings on context menu

Tags: windows-10, command-line, display-settings

Whenever I **right-click** on my desktop and click **Display Settings** or **Personalize**, this command prompt shows for a quarter of a second (luckily I was able to screenshot it).

It also does the same when I enter `ms-settings:display` on **Run** and I don't know why (I am the Administrator and my laptop has only 1 account).

[image: cmd prompt saying 'ERROR: Access is Denied']

But when I search **Display settings** or **Personalize** on the Start menu and click it, it opens with no problem. Any idea why does this happen?

**EDIT:** I have ran `sfc /scannow` and `DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /ScanHealth` on cmd and restarted my laptop.
[image: sfc and dism output on cmd]

However, the problem still exists.

Comment: I assume you have tried to restart your system?  I experienced a similar problem, which was caused by a pending update, the solution to that problem was to install the update by rebooting. If a reboot does not work I would try running and providing the output of SFC and DISM.  If no corruption is discovered I would perform an in-place repair.

Comment: I did restart the system after an update. Let me try SFC

Comment: I suggest you run and complete DISM first and then run SFC after that.  Restart after completing both.

Comment: @John I did what you said. Still, the problem is there

Comment: I have (infrequently) had difficulty with Context Menus. Try a Windows 10 Repair Install.  If Dropbox is running, exit Dropbox before the repair. https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10

Windows 10 is running, so click on the Download button (not Upgrade Button, select Run.

Comment: @John I have downloaded and opened `MediaCreationTool2004.exe` and Windows10 Logo appeared for a second. Am I doing it correct?

Comment: It should start to run by itself and may take a minute. If not, see where it downloaded and see if you can run from the download. It will be a big download (approx 3 GB)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108744/discussion-between-newbieguy-and-john).

Comment: Run Process Monitor, look for the process that is creating the 32-bit cmd prompt.  Look at the stack of the CreateProcess with Symbols enabled to see what's going on.  Link the PML if needed.

Comment: @HelpingHand The problem got fixed, thanks to John. I'll keep that in mind and update this if the problem comes back again.

Comment: If I post my answer to do a Repair Install, will you find that helpful?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have (infrequently) had difficulty with Context Menus.

Try a Windows 10 Repair Install. If Dropbox is running, exit Dropbox before the repair. microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10 Windows 10 is running, so click on the Download button (not Upgrade Button, select Run.

This will fix most problems and should help you here